# Multivariate Normal : expectation of X given Y is doubly-truncated

Tags: conditional-expectation, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let $(X, Y)$ be distributed as a multivariate normal with parameters

$$
\mu =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_X \\ \mu_Y
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\Sigma =
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_X^2 & \sigma_{XY} \\ \sigma_{XY} & \sigma_Y^2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

**I would like to calculate $E(X | y_1 < Y < y_2)$, where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are constants.**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_conditional_expectation), I have managed to work out that
$$
E(X | Y > y_1) = \mu_X + \frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y} \left[\frac{\phi\left(\frac{y_1 - \mu_y}{\sigma_Y}\right)}{1 - \Phi\left(\frac{y_1 - \mu_y}{\sigma_Y}\right)}\right]\\
E(X | Y < y_2) = \mu_X - \frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y} \left[\frac{\phi\left(\frac{y_2 - \mu_y}{\sigma_Y}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{y_2 - \mu_y}{\sigma_Y}\right)}\right]
,$$
where $\phi(\cdot)$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ are, respectively, the p.d.f. and the c.d.f. of the Normal distribution. I could not figure out how to calculate $E(X | y_1 < Y < y_2)$, though.

I have searched for an answer in similar posts from the Stack Exchange network, but I couldn't get a clue from them that would solve this issue. For the record, here are some of them:

1. [Conditional expectation in the multivariate normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/314172/27433)
2. [Expectation of conditional normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/103132/27433)
3. [Conditional expectation of bivariate normal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/224168/27433)
4. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2807096/83294

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/356023/expectation-of-truncated-normal/.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, thank you. I am studying the answers there and will post one here (since my question is different and the solution to it is but a step used in the answers posted there) ASAP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use the same approach in point 3. the conditional expectation
$$E(X|Y)=\mu_X+\sigma_{XY}\frac{Y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y^2}$$
Then take the expectation of the RHS of this expression given $y_1<Y<y_2$. The only random variable is $Y$ and this has conditional expectation of
$$E(Y|y_1<Y<y_2)=\mu_Y+\sigma_Y\left[\frac{\phi\left(\frac{y_1-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)-\phi\left(\frac{y_2-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{y_2-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{y_1-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)}\right]
$$
Plugging this in gives you
$$E(X|y_1<Y<y_2)=\mu_X+\frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y}\left[\frac{\phi\left(\frac{y_1-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)-\phi\left(\frac{y_2-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{y_2-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{y_1-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)}\right]
$$

this also contains your two answers as special cases $y_1\to-\infty$ and $y_2\to\infty$

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer, it helped me with a subsequential issue I was having over here.