# Calculate mean of $X$ when $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal and $Y$ is truncated above

Tags: mean, expected-value, multivariate-normal-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution

Suppose I have two random variable $X$ and $Y$ and they are distributed joint normally and $Y$ is truncated above by constant $c$

$$\begin{pmatrix} X \\ Y \end{pmatrix}  = TN\left(\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \mu_x \\ \mu_y \end{pmatrix}}_{\text{mean}},\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \sigma^2_x & \rho\sigma_x\sigma_y \\ \rho\sigma_x\sigma_y & \sigma^2_y \end{pmatrix}}_{\text{variance matrix}},\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} -\infty \\ -\infty \end{pmatrix}}_{\text{under bound}},\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \infty \\ c \end{pmatrix}}_{\text{upper bound}} \right),$$

From this distribution, I wonder if the mean of $X$ is $\mu_x$. From my calculation, the marginal density of $X$ is
$$f_X(x) = \frac{\Phi\left(\frac{c-\mu_y-\frac{\rho\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}(x-\mu_x)}{\sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}\sigma_y}\right)}{\Phi((c-\mu_y)/\sigma_y)}\frac{1}{\sigma_x}\phi((x-\mu_x)/\sigma_x), $$
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cdf of standard normal and $\phi$ is the pdf of standard normal.

I am not sure that if
$$\mu_x = \int xf_X(x)\,dx $$

Or maybe
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mu_x - \rho\sigma_x\left(\frac{\phi((c-\mu_y)/\sigma_y)}{\Phi((c-\mu_y)/\sigma_y)}\right) $$

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate of [Multivariate Normal : expectation of X given Y is doubly-truncated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385423/multivariate-normal-expectation-of-x-given-y-is-doubly-truncated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ conditional on $Y$ is not truncated, the [usual formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) for $EX|Y$ holds.  Hence, using the law of total expectation,
\begin{align}
EX&=EEX|Y\\&=E(\mu_x+\rho\frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y}(Y-\mu_y))\\&=\mu_x+\rho\frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y}(EY-\mu_y).
\end{align}
Since $Y$ marginally has a univariate [truncated normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution#One_sided_truncation_(of_lower_tail)%5B4%5D) distribution,
$$
EY=\mu_y - \frac{\phi(\frac{c-\mu_y}{\sigma_y})}{\Phi(\frac{c-\mu_y}{\sigma_y})}\sigma_y.
$$
Thus,
$$
EX=\mu_x-\rho\sigma_x\frac{\phi(\frac{c-\mu_y}{\sigma_y})}{\Phi(\frac{c-\mu_y}{\sigma_y})}.
$$

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Will it be $$EX=\mu_x-\rho\sigma_x\frac{\phi(\frac{c-\mu_y}{\sigma_y})}{\Phi(\frac{c-\mu_y}{\sigma_y})}$$? As $Y$ is truncated above?

Comment: @user1292919 Yes, you're absolutely right