Conditional expectation of a multivariate normal distribution
Let $(X,Y,Z)$ have a multivariate normal distribution:
\begin{align}
(X, Y, Z) \sim N\left(\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \rho_{xy} & \rho_{xz} \\
\rho_{xy} & 1 & \rho_{yz} \\
\rho_{xz} & \rho_{yz} & 1
\end{pmatrix}\right)
\end{align}
I'm trying to find the conditional expectation of the following:
$$E[X| Y > \tau_Y, Z > \tau_Z]$$
where $\tau_X$ and $\tau_Y$ are constants.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/639243/ex1-x2-x3-for-x1-x2-x3-multivariate-normal/639514#639514,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605480/random-number-generation-of-truncated-multivariate-normal-distribution/605490#605490
